# Process.Start() not performing as expected

Tags: c#, .net, security, process, uac

If I run `takeown /F "C:\Program Files\Borland /A /R /D Y` from an elevated command prompt, I'm given ownership of the `Borland` folder. But if I run the code below nothing happens. Tried running as Administrator and regular user.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\takeown.exe";
process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/F \"C:\\Program Files\\Borland\" /A /R /D Y";
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I have the same question too. I've tried writing a PowerShell script that uses runas to do some stuff with Services... no luck. It appears to me that runas != uac (in Powershell is asks for your password within the prompt and doesn't pop up the uac dialog). I'd love to find an answer to this too :)

Comment: Do you happen to have UAC enabled? It works for me doing it at work (and UAC is disabled). Maybe UAC is preventing you from doing it?

Comment: This is on Windows 8 and UAC is ON.

Comment: Hmm, maybe Windows 8 has a different (native) way of running processes? Is your program set to be a .net or winrt program? I'd imagine winrt has restrictions on what processes you can invoke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A format and re-install of Windows seemed to do the trick. I wish I had a better answer but after much searching, I found nothing that worked. Perhaps an existing security setting was preventing it from working.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have useshellexecute set to false on your startinfo object in order to be prompted by UAC

Comment: I added "process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;" but it didnt seem to change anything.

Comment: JimDel did you also have the verb=runas? It is both of them in combination that seem to accomplish the UAC prompt

Comment: I didn't notice you were on Windows 8, maybe Microsoft has changed something. But, if those two values are set I always recieved the UAC.

Comment: Thanks Alex. See my answer for what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
**Release** build(but not default "**Debug**") helps me.